# How can I use Livestream player in iOS/Android app?

Tags: android, ios, flash, live-streaming

You can watch video streams on [Livestream](http://new.livestream.com/home) by using their player.

Can it be embeded in iOS/Android application to track only one channel?

Comment: Off topic gang? Don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via HTML for mobile with LiveStream's [Mobile API](http://www.livestream.com/userguide/index.php?title=Mobile_API).

For example, in iOS you can do that like this via html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>iPhone Example:</h1>
<video width="300" height="225" 
   src="http://xmashablex.is.channel.livestream.com/onDemand/ls/mashable/pla_2bc0bbfa-cc39-4f80-b9ef-376b97da94a4/playlist.m3u8" 
   poster="http://www.livestream.com/filestore/user-files/chmashable/2010/06/08/d333a646-94aa-4035-a66e-1185bd885622_1.jpg" 
   controls="" 
   autoplay="true" 
   tabindex="0">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

And android/blackberry:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Android Example:</h1>
<a href="rtsp://xmashablex.is.channel.livestream.com:1935/onDemand/ls/mashable/pla_2bc0bbfa-cc39-4f80-b9ef-376b97da94a4" id="thumbnail">
<img width="320" height="240" 
src="http://www.livestream.com/filestore/user-files/chmashable/2010/06/08/d333a646-94aa-4035-a66e-1185bd885622_1.jpg" 
alt="thumbnail" title="thumbnail"/>
</a><br>
Click image to play
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't seem to find license policies. Is this free?

Comment: @vale4674 Do you mean can you use this with a free/premium account?

Comment: @vale4674 Sorry, but according to [THIS](http://www.livestream.com/forum/showthread.php?t=9958) post: `At this time, our mobile API is available only to paying Premium accounts on a long term commitment.`

Comment: I am able to display video with this local html file: `<html>
    <body>
        <h1>iPhone Example:</h1>
        <video width="300" height="225"
            src="http://xmashablex.is.channel.livestream.com/onDemand/ls/mashable/pla_2bc0bbfa-cc39-4f80-b9ef-376b97da94a4/playlist.m3u8"
            poster="http://www.livestream.com/filestore/user-files/chmashable/2010/06/08/d333a646-94aa-4035-a66e-1185bd885622_1.jpg"
            controls=""
            autoplay="true"
            tabindex="0">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: @vale4674 I am glad it works! Ask if you need any more help!

Comment: Well. What I need is to play this [channel](http://new.livestream.com/Fox8News/live/embed) e.g. If I set this URL for video source it shows play icon crossed and video can not be played.

Comment: @vale4674 OK, try this: `http://xfox8newsx.is.livestream-api.com:1935/livestreamiphone/fox8news/playlist.m3u8`

Comment: still no luck. You can see on [this image](http://www.pohrani.com/f/L/NO/2aCl9AHv/screen-shot-2013-01-03-a.png) how it is looking on iOS UIWebView.

Comment: Is this because I am trying to stream a channel and in yours example (in your answer), a regular video is streamed?