# using livestream video in iOS application

Tags: ios, ipad, live-streaming, twitch

I want to use video from some live streaming channel i.e. twitch, youtube in my iOS application without using their plugins. How can i do so?

I'm trying to get url of the video so that i can play it via moviePlayer or something else in my application. At the moment, i'm using OBS for uploading the live-stream on twitch.tv

I've found the following link, but again i'm unable to find the url of the video so can't use the solution mentioned [How can I use Livestream player in iOS/Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130473/how-can-i-use-livestream-player-in-ios-android-app)

Thanks,

Comment: I'm also trying to use twitch plugin for iOS but it's not working properly. It shows me a screen of my channel on Twitch with a play button, but when i click on it, video is not played most of the time (or is played after few minutes but not consistent).. I'm using "TKStreamPresentationModeRemainInApp" mode..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue using webView. For Youtube we've stream id and we put it in url as **"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoId"**.

For ustream i made url as **"https://www.ustream.tv/embed/channelId"**.

If you don't want to use webView then you can use helper libraries for these platforms i.e. YTPlayer, twitch etc.

Comment: If any one have any other better solution then do post here. Best,